# No command 'lint' found

Tags: android, command-line, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, lint

I want to generate lint report for my project.
So on my Ubuntu terminal I gave the command `lint my_prj_path`
but I'm getting below error,

```
No command 'lint' found, did you mean:
Command 'link' from package 'coreutils' (main)
Command 'jlint' from package 'jlint' (universe)
Command 'hlint' from package 'hlint' (universe)
Command 'line' from package 'util-linux' (main)
Command 'tint' from package 'tint' (universe)
Command 'dlint' from package 'dlint' (universe)
lint: command not found
```

May be its very basic question, but I can't find a solution. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: lint is located into sdk/tools directory. Did you tried that

Comment: yes, but same error even in /tools/, /platforms/ or /platform-tools/ dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**lint**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) is available into ***`/sdk/tools/`***. So you need to go to directory or add relative path before lint command, like

```
SDK_PATH/sdk/tools/lint project_path
```

Comment: When I tried it I got the error as ` To correctly analyze Gradle projects, you should run "gradlew :lint" instead`

Answer (score 0):

I made it that way:

Firstly, check that your `.bash_profile` file contains ANDROID_SDK_ROOT path]

Secondly, add `lint()` function:

```
function lint() {
    cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin;
    ./lint $1;
}
```

Now you can call `lint` commands via terminal, for example, `lint --list`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, navigate to android sdk tools directory and down to binaries `$ANDROID_ROOT/sdk/tools/bin`. Then call

```
./lint [flags] <project directory>
```

(note a call to `./lint` not just `lint`)

For example, to get a list of all lint-supported issues call:

```
./lint --list
```